# Когда правильно использовать слово "институт", а когда "институция"?

Tags: лексика, недопустимая-метка

Я задавала этот вопрос на "Большом вопросе" - в ответ [невнятица](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/instituty-i-institutsii-v-sovremennoy-ekonomicheskoy-teorii)...

[Пример употребления](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1701269-kogda-pravilno-ispolzovat-slovo-institut-a-kogda-institucija.html):

"Это закрепило применение термина «институт» и способствовало отказу от категории «институция» при описании феноменов соответствующего характера".

Что это за два зверя таких?

---

P. S. Прочитав ответ Artemix.

Нет, я в "Художественном журнале" проработала около пятнадцати лет, и там это слово чуть ли не у каждого автора...

**[Институции](http://azbuka.gif.ru/alfabet/i/institutes/)**

> ...Художественные институции - это всяческие полезные для художественной
>   жизни организации: музеи, галереи, художественные центры и прочая и
>   прочая - всего-то.
>
> Понятно, что художественные институции - это наше слабое место,
>   поскольку актуальное искусство в России и поныне находится в положении
>   пациента из старого анекдота: "Доктор, меня все игнорируют".
>
> Институции все же существуют, да и художественный процесс, который без
>   них в наше время уже немыслим, имеет место быть - как и положено,
>   вопреки обстоятельствам. Разумеется, о том, чтобы как-то оценивать их
>   деятельность, и речи быть не может, я просто постараюсь вспомнить: кто
>   у нас есть...

А вот другой источник:

[Термин «новый институционализм» впервые использовал куратор и критик Юнас Экеберг для описания деятельности небольших музеев и галерей начала 2000-х, вовлеченных в критическое искусство, образовательные и издательские практики...](http://theoryandpractice.ru/posts/8402-jonas-ekeberg-new-institutionalism)

И ещё, вовсе к арт-практике не относящийся пример употребления:

[Также и президентская институция, последовав примеру унтер-офицерской вдовы, вдруг превратилась в условность.](http://www.gazeta.ru/column/fishman/250321.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот там как раз, в вашем примере употребления, и есть ответ: в экономике "институт" это "организация", а "институция" (слова такого официально нет) - это правила, по которым институты действуют.

В русском языке оба этих значения имеет слово "институт" и чтобы их разделить и пытаются использовать слово "институция".

А на самом деле, это транслитерация английских терминов institute и institution.

Вот как институт определяется в словаре:

> ИНСТИТУ́Т, а, м. [фр. institut < лат. īnstitūtum установление, учреждение].1.Название нек-рых учебных заведений и научных учреждений.Медицинский и.||Ср. академия (во 2-м знач.), колледж, лицей, техникум, университет.2. ист.В России до 1917 г.: закрытое женское среднее учебное заведение для детей дворян.Институ́тка —воспитанница, ученица института.Институ́тский —относящийся к институту (в 1-м и 2-м знач.), институтам.3.Совокупность норм права в какой-н. области общественных отношений, та или иная форма общественного устройства.И. брака.
>   Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2008

Институция употребляется в смысле, описанном в пункте 3. "Совокупность норм права в какой-н. области общественных отношений".

---

В словарях встречается и старое значение "институция" в смысле организация. Но что касается экономики, точнее институциональной экономики, там это разделение присутствует именно в том смысле, который я привел в своем ответе. Возможно в художественном журнале "институция" используется не так как у экономистов.

Comment: В пункте 3 акцент на общественных отношениях и общественном же устройстве. Сюда попадает президентская институция?

Comment: В смысле "институт президенства" - да, это институция. Но можно ли сказать по-русски "президентская институция"? У меня нет ответа на такой вопрос.

Comment: У меня все ссылки в вопросе кликабельны. А ещё выгугливаются арбитражная институция и "Институции Гая" (кавычу  как название документа): "Институции представляют собой систематическое изложение всего римского частного права, как цивильного, так и преторского..."